# Box2d dynamic circle body passing through my static polygon body?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, box2d

I've created a "leaning wall" with box2d using the b2PolygonShape.SetAsArray function, and my player object (dynamic b2CircleShape) is able to push into it and eventually pass through it. However when I use SetAsBox it will no longer pass through it. Does anybody have an idea as to why this is happening?

The array I am using:

```
// array
var vertices:Array = [];
vertices[0] = new b2Vec2(0, 0);
vertices[1] = new b2Vec2(0, 506);
vertices[2] = new b2Vec2(50, 506);
vertices[3] = new b2Vec2(100, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse the order of these vertices so that the polygon is 'wound' counter-clockwise.

Comment: Oh wow, that worked. What do you mean by "'wound' counter-clockwise" because reversing them would put them in clockwise order wouldn't it? Thanks for the help though.

Comment: ...? I'm getting a little confused with all the reversing and countering :) In any case, counter-clockwise is what you want, and the order you have those in your question is clockwise.

Comment: Ok, I'll remember that for future use ^^